# A man asked for my username, password, account number and routing number. Do I need to be worried?

Tags: bank-account, scams, debit-card

A man wants to transfer money to my [Green Dot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Dot_Corporation) debit card. He asked for my username, password, account number and routing number. However, there is no money in the account. Should I still be worried?

Comment: He asked for these details. Did you give him anything? How do you know him?

Comment: Not having money in the account is no protection.  Account balances can go negative, and these scammers know just how to make it happen.  On top of that, money laundering and other criminal activity can land you in hot water even if you get to *keep some money.*. (Perhaps especially so if you keep some.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Someone wants my account details and password to transfer money to me](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/40252/someone-wants-my-account-details-and-password-to-transfer-money-to-me)

Comment: As a general rule, never give anybody your password to anything for any reason.

Answer (score 5):

> **He asked for my username, password, account number and routing number. However, there is no money in the account. Should I still be worried?**

You should, it would be reckless and negligent to provide that information even though there is no money in the account.

Green Dot's terms include

> establish a username and password which you will keep secure. You agree
> not to provide access to your Account together with your user username and password to others. You are solely responsible for protecting the security of your Account on your device

If you give a username and password to other people, you are in breach of these terms and conditions - this is a breach of contract. You are likely to be held accountable for any consequent loss to Green Dot.

For example if this man uses your account to launder money for a criminal organisation - you are the person that law enforcement will come looking for first. In the worst case you may have to provide a law court with convincing evidence that this man exists and that you could not have been reasonably expected to have known of the terms and conditions you breached. If the man runs up some kind of debt or overdraft, you may be held responsible for repayment.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you probably got scammed. I do not know what product you are talking about, but if someone got your password, you got scammed.  Change your password as fast as possible.